# How can I create a single webdriver instance in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am in the midst of creating an automation framework in Python, but I am stuck in creating a single instance of web driver.
Here's an excerpt of my framework design:

1. A separate *Driver.py* file which has the set up to create a web driver instance

   ```
    from selenium import webdriver

    class Driver:
        # Creating a class variable
        Instance = None

            @staticmethod
            def Initialize():
                Instance = webdriver.Firefox()
                return Instance
   ```
2. Use this file in all areas of framework like:

   ```
    from Driver import Driver

    class LoginPage:
        @staticmethod
        def GoToURL():
            Driver.Instance.get("sample url")

        @staticmethod
        def Login():
            Driver.Instance.find_element_by_id("session_key-login").send_keys("sample@gmail.com")
            Driver.Instance.find_element_by_id("session_password-login").send_keys("sample_password")
            Driver.Instance.find_element_by_id("btn-primary").click()
   ```

The problem is **Driver.Instance.get()** or for that matter **Driver.Instance.find_element...** are throwing errors. Probably, it is not recognizing Driver.Instance here.

Comment: You should post the error stack trace too.

Comment: What errors are they throwing? Obviously it has nothing to do with you not being able to create that instance (which is what you're asking according to the title). Sounds like an exception thrown by the `webdriver.get` method. Possibly your URL is ill-formed or something.

Comment: `btn-primary` is a CSS **class** not **id**.

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' as the error message

Comment: Provide the `html` as well if possible

Comment: @Saifur: The problem was just in the way a single instance was created and also in the way it was imported in different modules. It is resolved now. You can see my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the solution to my question!!!
Instead of creating a class variable in file Driver.py, I did this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

Instance = None

def Initialize():
    global Instance
    Instance = webdriver.Chrome("driver path")
    Instance.implicitly_wait(5)
    return Instance
    
def CloseDriver():
    global Instance
    Instance.quit()
```

Places where I have to use this instance, I do this:

```py
import Driver

class LoginPage:
    @staticmethod
    def GoToURL():
        Driver.Instance.get("sample url")
        
    @staticmethod
    def Login():
        Driver.Instance.find_element_by_id("session_key-login").send_keys("sample username")
        Driver.Instance.find_element_by_id("session_password-login").send_keys("sample password")
        Driver.Instance.find_element_by_id("btn-primary").click()
```

The file from which I am running this test is this:

```py
import unittest
import Driver
from LoginPage import LoginPage

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Driver.Initialize()
        
    def testUserCanLogin(self):
        #Go to the login url
        LoginPage.GoToURL()
        #Enter username, password and hit sign in
        LoginPage.Login()
        #On the top right corner, check that correct user has logged in
        
    def tearDown(self):
        Driver.CloseDriver()
```

This is working like a charm...

Comment: Well, using globals shouldn't be a proper answer to anything :-(